how to export different version of ingress route
When I using this command to export kubernetes 1.29 ingress route:
kubectl get ingressroute -o yaml --all-namespaces > ingress-route.yaml

but i just seem one api version's ingress route:
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute

there is another apiVersion's ingress route in the kubernetes cluster:
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute

I can not found the traefik.io/v1alpha1 from the output file, how to export both apiVersion of ingress route? This is the kubectl output:
➜  ~ kubectl get ingressroute --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                      AGE
reddwarf-pro   official-website-route    715d
reddwarf-pro   react-admin-new-route     2y119d
reddwarf-pro   react-admin-route         2y335d
reddwarf-pro   snap-web-route            458d
reddwarf-pro   tex-websocket-route       344d
reddwarf-pro   tool-web-route            463d
sre            apollo-dev-config-route   2y339d
sre            apollo-route              2y339d 

and this is the ingress route with traefik.io in lens:

and this is the traefik.containo.us in lens:

